# Transformations to string to get the same result

Tags: php

I have this project in php in which my goal is to compare data from the database with some data I get from outlook, and if it's the same data i skip to the next row, otherwise I update.

The data in the DB comes like below:

```
$db = 'Meeting F2F Planung Meetings/Bilas 2018 2017-09-19 10:002017-09-19 12:0000KI Büro'
```

The data from outlook:

```
$outlook = 'Meeting F2F Planung Meetings/Bilas 2018<font size="2"><span style="font-size:10pt;"><div class="PlainText">&nbsp;</div></span></font>2017-09-19 10:002017-09-19 12:0000KI BÃ¼ro'
```

What i do is to get the data from outlook look like the one in DB is:

```
$outlook = (strip_tags(html_entity_decode($outlook)));
```

I still get the `'BÃ¼ro'` when I transfrom the data from outlook, so when i compare $outlook and $event, they appear as not equal so in my project it updates.

By asking here I got to the code above, but in this case it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: To solve this problem, please use `$string = utf8_encode($string);` For more information please check [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_utf8_encode.asp)

Comment: Additional there is the matter, that `$db` and `$outlook` never will be the same. You have to remove the HTML-tags.

Comment: @SacrumDeus but strip_tags removes the tags

Comment: Ok. Then just add `utf8_encode( )`. However, please dont make too long statements....it will be unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    $outlook = utf8_decode(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($outlook))); 
    echo $outlook;